# Expression for "finding something accidentally"

Tags: expressions

I am writing a short story and I need to find an expression for "*finding something accidentally*".   My main character in the story finds a blue envelope below the computer keyboard.

Comment: The noun is _serendipity_ and the adjective is _serendipitous_. It comes from a story about the mythical princes of Serendip, who were always encountering marvelous coincidences.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I'm wondering why you didn't post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stumbled on" is usually the term, i.e. Alexander Fleming stumbled on penicillin because of an accident involving moldy potato salad and petri dishes, but I'm not sure if that will work for you in this case. It could also be described as an "incidental find", something that has been picked up as part of other activity and without realising it's significance until later. The protagonist could describe the situation by saying "incidentally I picked this up early, I don't know if it's important" or something of that nature.

Comment: Or *stumbled upon*.

Comment: @JasonBassford True, I've obviously been consuming too much American media of late.

Answer (score 0):

**chance upon**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/chance+upon)

find unexpectedly; "the archeologists chanced upon an old tomb"; "she struck a goldmine"; "The hikers finally struck the main path to the lake"